# jsf call managed bean method from another managed bean

Tags: jsf-2

I am using JSF 2.x in my project.

I have two pages and two managed beans (request scoped) for these two pages.

**Page 1** is loaded after user clicks on a link on Home page. This link calls view() method of Bean1 (with request parameter ID=some value) in which we load some data from DB (based on ID) and then redirects to page 1 where this data is displayed.

Later, user navigates from page 1 to page 2 and here we pass the same ID to the page 2.

On **page 2**, user enters data and clicks on Save button. This will call saveDetails() method of Bean 2.

After the saveDetails() method I want to **redirect to page 1** by calling Bean1's view() method and passing the ID as request parameter. I cannot redirect directly to page1 because then there will be no data to display as the bean1 is request scoped.

Hence, I want to call bean1.view() with request parameter ID. I.e. I want to achieve the same behavior as if user has clicked on the link on Home page.

How to achieve this?

Here is the code so far:

```
    @ManagedBean
@Component
@RequestScoped
@Scope("request")
// bean for page1
public class ModifyCDSPageBean extends BasePageBean {
private DisplayTicket ticket;
private String selectedCDS;
...
...
// CDS List
private static Map<String, String> cdsList = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

@Autowired
TicketConsoleGTRDao ticketConsoleGTRDao;

private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(ModifyCDSPageBean.class);

public String viewTicketDetails() {
    populateCDSList();

    ....
    // Method updated to set DisplayInfoTravail
    String id_incident = getRequestParameterValue(TicketConstants.ID_INCIDENT);
    List<InfoTravail> travailsList = 
    ticketConsoleGTRDao.findMatchingTrvailInformation(id_incident);

    ....

    return NavigationConstants.PAGE_MODIFY_CDS;
}
...
...
}


@ManagedBean
@Component
@RequestScoped
@Scope("request")
//Bean for page 2
public class CreateInfoTravailPageBean extends BasePageBean {

private String selectedTypeInfoTravail;

...
...

@Autowired
TicketConsoleGTRDao ticketConsoleGTRDao;

private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(CreateInfoTravailPageBean.class);

public String viewInfoTravail() {
    populateTypeInfoTravailList();
    ...
    ...
    return NavigationConstants.PAGE_CREATE_INFO_TRAVAIL;
}

public String saveInfoTravail() {
    String idIncident = getRequestParameterValue(TicketConstants.ID_INCIDENT);
    infoTravail.setTicketId(idIncident);
    infoTravail.setDate_creation(formatter.format(new Date()));

    // HERE I WANT TO CALL ModifyCDSPageBean.viewTicketDetails() method 
    // pass id_incident as request parameter while making this call
    // because if you check  ModifyCDSPageBean.viewTicketDetails above it 
    // looks for request parameter id_incident

}
```

Comment: If this parameter is something you want to keep alive that long, maybe putting it into session scope is an option?

Comment: Can you please show your code to see what you have done so far?

Comment: @mabi, even if I put this parameter in session, this does not solve my problem. I want to call method of another managed bean into the current bean. see code above for details. thanks.

Comment: @SRy, I have added the code in my questions. thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-reading your requirements, it sounds like you want a page initialization code. That is, turn around the flow and don't let entry-points into your `page1` call the bean's code, let the bean do that itself:

```
@ManagedBean @RequestScoped
public class ModifyCDSPageBean {
    @Inject @Param(name = TicketConstants.ID_INCIDENT)
    private ParamValue<Long> myParam;

    @Autowired
    private TicketConsoleGTRDao dao;

    private List<InfoTravail> travailsList;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        if (myParam.getValue() != null) {
            // do stuff based on the param being set
            travailsList = dao.findById(myParam.getValue());
        }
    }
    // getter for travailsList
}
```

And then include the parameter in your navigation from bean2:

```
public class Bean2 {
    public String save() {
        String idIncident = getRequestParameterValue(TicketConstants.ID_INCIDENT);
        // do stuff and then return to page1, passing parameter ID_INCIDENT
        return String.format("page1?faces-redirect=true&%s=%s", 
            TicketConstants.ID_INCIDENT, idIncident);
}
```

If you don't need to execute your view preparation code *every* time you create `ModifyCDSPageBean` (ie, if it's used on other pages, too), look into calling it on your page. If you've got JSF-2.2, try `<f:viewAction action="#{modifyCDSPageBean.init}">` or on older versions, `<f:event listener="#{modifyCDSPageBean.init()}" type="preRenderView">`.

Note that `@PostConstruct` with a `@RequestScoped` bean will re-create the bean with each AJAX-request, which is probably not what you want. In that case, try `@ViewScoped`.

My code example uses omnifaces' [@Param](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/cdi/Param) for my lack of knowledge of spring. Maybe they have something similar in the toolkit already (or just call your `getRequestParameterValue` from the bean method).

Comment: Hi, sorry I did not understand how this will solve my problem. To be specific, I want to call ModifyCDSPageBean.viewTicketDetails() method from CreateInfoTravailPageBean.saveInfoTravail(). @PostConstruct is new for me and I read it online and I understand everytime the bean is instanciated, init() method will be called. This looks like something that will solve my problem if I put the id_incident (ticketid) in session and let init() method read it from session. Not sure if I understand this correctly. Can you confirm or elaborate a little? Thanks

Comment: @user3091282 No need for session scope in this case. I don't know what your `getRequestParameterValue` method looks like, but chances are it will work unmodified in `init` (eg, you can read from `FacesContext` in there). I've updated the post to include an example for the second page bean.